# Problems when adding Foreign Key Constraints w/ psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, psycopg2

I'm trying to add a Foreign Key constraint to an existing table. The reason why I don't just add the foreign keys in the inititial query (the query that creates the table), is because I will have multiple references that varies (i.e., some tables will have more references than others), and using ALTER TABLE seems like the only option when dealing with uncertainty.

Now, I have the following problem: I try to add a foreign key, that should point to another table in the same schema. This is the code:

```
alter_query = """
                ALTER TABLE {schema}.{table}
                ADD CONSTRAINT {fk} FOREIGN KEY ({hashKey})
                REFERENCES {reference} ({hub_hash});
                """

#Note, that i = "company" in this example.

final_alter_query = sql.SQL(alter_query).format(
                                             schema=sql.Identifier(clientID),
                                             table=sql.Identifier(tableName),
                                             fk=sql.Identifier(tableName+"_"+i+"_hash_key_fk"),
                                             hashKey=sql.Identifier(i+"_hash_key"),
                                             reference=sql.Identifier(clientID+".hub_"+i),
                                             hub_hash=sql.Identifier(i+"_hash_key")
                                             )
```

To make it a bit clearer, the actual SQL generated is:

```
    ALTER TABLE "c0001000_business_vault"."lnk_company_registration"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "lnk_company_registration_company_hash_key_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("company_hash_key")
    REFERENCES "c0001000_business_vault.hub_company" ("company_hash_key");
```

It gives the following error: (and yes, the relation does exist)

```
cur2.execute(final_alter)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "c0001000_business_vault.hub_company" does not exist
```

I don't understand why it suddenly gives me errors, because it works when I use format without sql.Identifier, but I have to do it this way according to psycopg2 documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psycopg2 is right in complaining. I think the generated SQL will not work even if submitted through psql or other client.

The schema and table quoting should not include the . separator. Get it to generate this instead:

```
 ALTER TABLE "c0001000_business_vault"."lnk_company_registration"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "lnk_company_registration_company_hash_key_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("company_hash_key")
    REFERENCES "c0001000_business_vault"."hub_company" ("company_hash_key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related with lack of `"`.

Try modify this line:

```
reference=sql.Identifier(clientID+".hub_"+i),
```

To this:

```
reference=sql.Identifier(clientID+"\".\"hub_"+i),
```

Comment: as expected, it doesn't solve it. The problem is that it somehow doesn't recognise the other table I'm referring to.